# Grails Upgrade to 2.5.5 - Unresolved dependencies - groovy-all 2.4.5

Tags: grails, dependency-management

I am trying to upgrade my grails application from 2.0.0 to 2.5.5, running into Unresolved dependencies for groovy-all jar. 
Dependency resolver in BuildConfig.groovy is set to ivy. Also, location %USERPROFILE%/.grails/ivy-cache/org.codehaus.groovy contains groovy-all.jar of version 2.4.5

Java is set to JDK7

Exact error:
org.codehaus.groovy#groovy-all;2.4.5: configuration not found in org.codehaus.groovy#groovy-all;2.4.5: 'master'. It was required from org.grails#grails-core;2.5.5 compile

BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "ivy"

repositories {
    mavenRepo "link to company specific repo"
    mavenCentral()
}


plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.10"
    runtime ":jquery:1.7.1"
    runtime ":resources:1.1.5"
    runtime ":bubbling:1.5.1"
    runtime ":calendar:1.2.1"
    runtime ":code-coverage:1.1.6"
    runtime ":jsecurity:0.3"
    runtime ":tomcat:7.0.42"
    runtime ":webflow:1.3.7"
    runtime ":webtest:1.1.5.1"
    runtime ":yui:2.8.2.1"

    build ":tomcat:7.0.70"
}
```

Please help. Let me know if any additional details needed.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue. Unfortunately, the work-around suggested below is not working for me. My only option at this point is to use grails 2.5.4 instead. Unless anyone has another suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Problem mentioned above is specific to Grails version 2.5.5, my workaround has worked for me but with this workaround I cannot go ahead with version 2.5.5 as it will be a problem in Continuous integration, production deployment, etc. So because of this issue we have moved to version 2.5.4. So it is a good option to point to Grails version 2.5.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After spending lot of time finding reason for this issue, I came across an issue reported in Grails version 2.5.5 (https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10011)  So before going to my project, tried to execute basic grails command "grails-createapp". This command also failed with error mentioned in question above.

Solution in our case was to

```
     1. Remove Grails version 2.5.5 (if this is already installed)
     2. Download/install Grails version 2.5.4
     3. Run basic command grails-createapp. This runs fine and an app is created.
     4. Remove Grails version 2.5.4
     5. Install Grails version 2.5.5 now
     6. Run command - grails createapp (this starts working now)
```

Strange issue :)

Comment: Indeed a strange one. It's possible to 'solve' the issue by setting dependency resolver in _BuildConfig.groovy_ to _maven_, a default value in generated file anyway, but there is no file upon call to `create-app` and default resolver with no configuration is _ivy_ which seems to be somehow buggy in this grails version. I posted a bit more of explanation under the issue you linked to: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10011#issuecomment-245138488

Answer (score 3):

For upgrade to version  2.5.5 add to your BuildConfig dependencies the line

`compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.6'`

This worked for me.